# Email validation in Portable/.NETcore (Modern-UI) application

Tags: c#, email-validation, modern-ui

**What is a good approach to validating emails in a portable application, specifically a Modern UI application?** I do not wish to have to reinvent the wheel and I'm not terribly keen on using a wall of regex.

My personal problem is that I have validation on my server side, but I would like to have some
validation in the client.

Here is a suggested method for a non-portable app:
[How to: Verify that Strings Are in Valid Email Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This can be copied into a portable context if `DomainMapper()` is omitted , **but how can DomainMapper be best disentangled here?** This is my favoured solution, as in my personal case I can accept some invalid email addresses passing through my client.

Another approach is to catch exceptions from `System.Net.MailAddress` , which isn't supported in a portable context either. (The MS recommended way , I think)

Does anyone know any other appropriate solutions? Is the linked method (sans DomainMapper) the best? If so, is there a way to reimplement DomainMapper in a portable context?

Answer (score 0):

Just deal with the Unicode in a simpler way, by converting to an Ascii character. That way all that you need is `System.Text.RegularExpressions` which is available as portable.

This passes all the given tests on the MS page, can't imagine its less permissive. If there bad emails that get through its not a big deal, since real validation should be on the server side anyway.

```cs
public static class RegexUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Portible version of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    /// More permissive validation for client side.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strIn"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIn))    
            return false;

        //Replace all unicode chars with ascii "A"
        strIn = Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\x0d\x0a\x20-\x7e\t]", "A");

        // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format. 
        try
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
                  @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                  @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer fails some unit tests (find email addresses to be invalid when they aren't). [Can I stop validating email addresses now please?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127065/can-i-stop-validating-email-addresses-now-please)

Comment: When you try to validate email addresses with regular expressions you now have 2 problems